# Do something with Apache's root PID before it forks

Tags: apache-2.2, init, pid

I need to set a property on the root Apache process which in inherited by its children (e.g. oom_adj, cgroup membership). However, Apache will fork itself as soon as it starts.

- Using $$ in the init.d script doesn't seem to work - nothing is affected after the init script exits.
- Using the value from the PID file is too late - only the root process is affected, after it has created workers.

Any solutions?
(aside from hacky ideas like enumerating "apache2" processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $$ in the init.d script didn't work, but using it in a separate script called by the init.d script worked.